# How to bubble sort a string?

Tags: c++

I am trying to get an input from the user and bubble sort that input then output the result. My code:

```
    #include<iostream>
    using namespace std;
    class bubble
    {
    public :

        string arr[20];

        //Number of elements in array
        int n;

        //Function to accept array elements
        void read()
        {
            while(1)
            {
                cout<<"\nEnter the number of elements in the array:";
                cin>>n;
                if(n<=20)

                    break;
                else
                    cout<<"\n Array can have maximum 20 elements \n";
            }
            //display the header
            cout<<"\n";
            cout<<"----------------------\n";
            cout<<"Enter array elements \n";
            cout<<"----------------------\n";

            //Get array elements
            for( int i=0; i<n ;i++ )
            {
                cout<<"<"<<i+1<<"> ";
                cin>>arr[i];
            }
        }
        //Bubble sort function
        void bubblesort()
        {
            for( int i=1;i<n ;i++ )//for n-1 passes
            {
                //In pass i,compare the first n-i elements
                //with their next elements
                for( int j=0; j<n-1; j++)
                {
                    if(arr[j] > arr[j+1])
                    {
                        string temp;
                        temp = arr[j];
                        arr[j] = arr[j+1];
                        arr[j+1] = temp;

                    }

                }
            }
        }
        void display()
        {
            cout<<endl;
            cout<<"----------------------\n";
            cout<<"Sorted array elements \n";
            cout<<"----------------------\n";
            for( int j=0; j<n; j++)
                cout<<arr[j]<<endl;
        }
};
int main()
{
    //Instantiate an instance of class
    bubble list;
    // Function call to accept array elements
    list.read();
    // Function call to sort array
    list.bubblesort();
    //Function call to display the sorted array
    list.display();
    return 0;
}
```

The code is running fine, but it doesn't accept the value of whitespace or indent in the string as an input. Is there a way to make it accept these values?

Comment: The error is pretty self-explaining. Take a closer look at line 59, and the `temp` variable declaration.

Comment: @user3467152: You modified your original question so that the problem is now a completely different one. Please don't do that. People who read the question and answers later will be confused. You should instead post new questions for new problems.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll have to change the type of `temp` to `std::string`. `int` will only work with integer numbers for obvious reasons.

If you encounter such compiler errors, always try to understand the error message first. Why would the program try to convert a string to an integer?

Then, look at the mentioned line (first number after the file name). Keep in mind that this number might be off in case you're using preprocessor macros.

If you go to that line, you'll notice that it's the following:

```
temp = arr[j];
```

Going back to the error message, it's pretty obvious that in this line you're trying to assign a string value to an integer:

```
integer = string;
```

Since you want strings, you'll have to see where `temp` is defined. Going up you'll hit the following line:

```
int temp;
```

Bingo! Since you know you'll need a string (and the variable isn't used anywhere else), you can now just swap the type to `std::string` and you're done:

```
string temp;
```

Comment: Thanks for your explanation, got it fixed but do you have an idea of how to make it accept whitespace as an input?

Comment: Do you want to skip whitespaces? Because by default it should compare whitespaces as well.

Answer (score 1):

1. **Don't use raw arrays.** Use `std::vector<std::string>`. Then the strange magic-number limitation of 20 will go away, too.
2. I think using a class just complicates things here. Use free-standing functions and pass `std::vector<std::string> &` as an argument.
3. Mind that C++ already provides sorting. See [`std::sort`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/sort) and related sorting functions and see if they fit your needs.
4. In C++, you don't initialize variables and set their starting value later (as is the case with your `int temp`). It's one pass: `int temp = /* starting value */;`. However, note that the statement is wrong anyway, because you are trying to set a string to an int.

Here's a hint how you may change your sort function, based on what you already have:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

void bubblesort(std::vector<std::string> &strings)
{
    typedef std::vector<std::string>::size_type size_type;
    for (size_type i = 1; i < strings.size(); ++i) // for n-1 passes
    {
        // In pass i,compare the first n-i elements
        // with their next elements
        for (size_type j = 0; j < (strings.size() - 1); ++j)
        {
            if(strings[j] > strings[j+1])
            {
                std::string const temp = strings[j];
                strings[j] = strings[j + 1];
                strings[j+1] = temp;
            }
        }
    }
}

int main()
{
    std::vector<std::string> strings;
    strings.push_back("foo");
    strings.push_back("bar");
    strings.push_back("foobar");

    bubblesort(strings);

    for (std::vector<std::string>::const_iterator iter = strings.begin(); iter != strings.end(); ++iter)
    {
        std::cout << *iter << "\n";
    }
}
```